# WPF: how can I have ListViewItems fit the window width and use TextEllipsis

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbar, listviewitem

I'm currently working with a ListView. Its ListViewItems consist of a left-aligned TextBlock and a right-aligned Button:

[image: The ListView in an uncomplicated state.]

Now, I'd like to have my Items *always* display the Button and shorten the TextBlock accordingly, so they don't need to display a ScrollBar:

[image: The ListView's intended behavior.]

Unfortunately, right now that doesn't work:

[image: The ListView's current behavior.]

What can I do to make it work?
Here's my example code:

```
<Window x:Class="JansWpfTestUmgebung.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ListView x:Name="AllItemsList"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListViewItem>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
                       Text="Item 1 with a very long description"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="Modify" />
        </Grid>
    </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>Item 3</ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Thanks for any hints! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by forcing a size on the button column:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        x:Class="JansWpfTestUmgebung.MainWindow"
        d:DesignWidth="394">
    <ListView x:Name="AllItemsList"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListViewItem>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="45" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
                Text="Item 1 with a very long description"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Content="Modify"/>
        </Grid>
    </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem Content="Item 2"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Item 3"/>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

The way it was, It does its best to keep the * sized column as big as possible, at the expense of the Auto sized column.  But a fixed size will win out against a * sized.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your code works for me. Interestingly enough, it doesn't seem to be the fixed width of the Button column alone, but also the explicit disabling of the ScrollBar that you added as well. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Ah.  No problem. <S>  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The Most important Parts are these

```
<ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"/>
```

That way your ListViewItems will fill the space, and the disabled horizontal scroll bar will prevent them from taking up more space.

My code looks like this

```
<ListView HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSourceList}"
          Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SearchBox}"
          >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                               Text="{Binding Name}" 
                               TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                               Text="{Binding Tag}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                               FontWeight="Bold" 
                               Foreground="LightGray"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```